# Interesting quirk of $1.618033989^2$

Tags: number-theory, functions

Squaring one of the zeroes of $f(x)=x^2-x-1$, if we write the zeros as $x=(1+q)$, where (needless to say), $q=x-1$, squaring said zero gives me $x^2=(2+q)$.

Stated differently, if $f(x)=0$, then the zeroes of $f$ are:

$$\left\lbrace\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right\rbrace$$

Interestingly, numerically, the first zero is $1.618033989$, squaring it yields $2.618033989$.

Of course, it can be evaluated algebraically,, since: $x=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ can be written as:
$$x=1+\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$$
$$x^2=\Biggl( 1+\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2} \Biggr)^2=1^2+2\cdot\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}+\Biggl(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\Biggr)^2$$
$$x^2=\frac{6}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{5}=2+\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$$

Are there other numbers like this? Forgive my impudence.

Comment: Other numbers like what?

Comment: Your number is defined by the property that $\alpha^2=\alpha +1$ .  There are only two numbers with that property (since quadratics have two roots, generally).

Comment: Of course, if $x^2$ equals $x+1$, then $x^2-x-1=0$, which is the equation you started with.

Comment: What do you mean by _There are only two numbers..._? @lulu

Comment: The equation $x^2-x-1=0$ is a quadratic.  It has exactly two solutions, given by the quadratic formula.

Comment: Also notice the inverse, $1/\phi=0.618033989$.

Comment: @Yves Daoust, i just realized that it is the golden mean. Very interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your question is about numbers keeping the same fractional part after squaring, it suffices to solve

$$x^2=x+n$$ where $n$ is an integer.

With $n=10$,
$$(3.7015621187\cdots)^2=13.7015621187\cdots$$